# Get last record of every user

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So my table looks like this

`PK1 | PK2 | User(not unique)| value 1 | value 2| timestamp` when added

I want to get most recent values for value 1 and value 2 for every user. How would I achieve this?

Also, PKs are not unique on their own, but in combination.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use PostgreSQL's proprietary `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on ("User") *
from the_table
order by "User", "timestamp" desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PK1, PK2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT PK1, PK2, value1, value2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```